# Selecting first element in the array column in hive

Tags: arrays, hive, hiveql

I am trying select the second element in the array column, delimited by pipe in hive. How can i achieve it?

Input

```
["John Doe|ABC","Jane Doe|XYZ"]
```

Output

```
["ABC","XYZ"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Explode array, take second element using split and collect array again. For example like this:

```
select t.myarray original_array, collect_list(split(e.element,'\\|')[1]) result_array
  from input_table t
       lateral view explode(t.myarray) e as element
 group by t.myarray
```